# c++ and sfml compiling issues

Tags: c++, sfml

I have simple program made with SFML and CPP, but everytime i start program for more that 1 try, I get an errors:

```
_main already defined in main.obj
one or more multiply defined symbols found (.exe file)
```

I tried to rename the main function(it works for one time then same error)

then i tried to delete .exe and .obj files in project folder (that didnt worked either)

I also switched between Debug/Release debugers (didnt worked)

here is [code](https://codeshare.io/2WgoPY)

thx for any help

(Im sorry for text structure and my english,also im new in cpp and sfml)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is telling you that your main() function is defined multiple times. And if we look at your code, we see that...

```
///////////////////////////////////////////-----Player.cpp------/////////////////////////////////

#include "Player.h"
#include "main.cpp"
```

...you #include your *main.cpp* in *player.cpp*, which causes the main function to be redefined. You don't need to #include *main.cpp* anywhere. `Player` doesn't need to know the existence of main.cpp in order to compile.

In general, you don't include **.cpp** files, but you especially should not include main.cpp anywhere.

Comment: ok thx for the help (this is good exp for me)